# Show gif from directory in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gif

How to show gif from the directory in Flutter that was downloaded earlier. I have tried Image.asset and other way but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to put the gif in a directory (eg: assets) in the project's root folder.
2. Then in pubspec.yaml you have to put the following code.

```
  assets:
    - assets/image.gif
```

3. Then in flutter code you can call `Image.asset('assets/image.gif')` to display the gif.